# Android Tabs: don't display the text underneath

Tags: android, android-layout

Maybe I'm not reading it carefully enough, but the [Tab Layout tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) doesn't specify how to display a tab without the icon or without the text underneath. Are either of these possible? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

For tab without icon

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",null)
                  .setContent(intent);
```

For tab without text

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                  .setContent(intent);
```

Of course, these are just lee way of doing them. For more complicated view on tabs, you may want to have a customized view and use `setIndicator (View view)` method to get your desired look.