# TabLayout with icons only instead of text

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

I don't know how to use only icons instead of texts in tabs in my TabsAccessorAdapter Activity. Some one can help me adapting the existing code. I tried finding out but didn't get any success.

I also do not know if this is the best way to create and display a TabLayout I hope you can help me.

My code:

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class TabsAccessorAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public TabsAccessorAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                ChatsFragment chatsFragment = new ChatsFragment();
                return chatsFragment;

            case 1:
                ContactsFragment contactsFragment = new ContactsFragment();
                return contactsFragment;

            case 2:
                RequestsFragment requestsFragment = new RequestsFragment();
                return requestsFragment;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return "Conversas";

            case 1:
                return "Contactos";

            case 2:
                return "Pedidos";

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Design support library tabs with only icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165306/design-support-library-tabs-with-only-icons)

Comment: As @dotGitignore said, just returning an empty string for `getPageTitle()` would do it! E.g. `getPageTitle(int position) { return "";  }`.

Comment: Thanks for the help I already got! :D